# Value produced by pointer subtraction in a given C code

Tags: c

After executing the code shown below, I get output as 4.

Can anyone explain what is happening in this code.

From my understanding :

Address of a[1] ie array element 20's address is stored in pointer variable p and 60's address is stored in variable q. q-p is done and it gets printed. But 
I expected the output to be something different.

For example considering start address of 1st element to be 100  and each element takes 2 bytes for integer. then a[0] address is 100, a[1] 102, a[2] 104, a[3] 106, a[4] 108 ,a[5] 110.

now address of a[5] -address of a[1] = 110-102 = 8

But value is 4. Any explanation for it. Where am I missing somthing?

[Here](http://codepad.org/RxfcrqY2) (codepad link) is the C code:

```
int main()
{
        int a[] = { 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60 };
        int *p = &a[1], *q = &a[5];
        printf("%d",q - p);
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Because `5 - 1 = 4`, the differnce in the index values.

Comment: because int pointers count mem addresses in steps, 4 represents the amount of memory / sizeof(int) between a[1] and a[5].

Comment: You'll need `*q - *p` if you want the values to be subtracted. What you currently do is subtracting their memory values (which is no different than just doing 5 - 1).

Comment: "*I get output as 4.*" and which result did you expect?

Comment: @alk can you please see the above question now. I edited them.

Comment: You want to read on how C does pointer arithmetic. As others pointed out its results depend on the type of the pointer. In Standard-C one may not perform pointer arithmetic on `void`-pointers.

Comment: And one more thing: Integers are typically 4 bytes nowadays.

Answer (score 2):

When you subtract pointers into the same array, you get the same difference as if you subtracted the corresponding indexes. C pointer arithmetic works this way to protect you from having to factor in the size of the array element.

Therefore, subtracting the address of `a[i]` from the address of `a[j]` gives you the same result as subtracting `i` from `j`.

Note that the result of subtraction is of type [`ptrdiff_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/ptrdiff_t), which may not fit into an integer.

Answer (score 1):

Pointer differences count the difference in `sizeof(pointed_to_elem)`. If you want raw byte difference, cast to `char*`, or use `char*` pointers.

```
printf("%d",(char*)q - (char*)p);
```

Or

```
char *p = (char*)&a[1], *q = (char*)&a[5];
```

Answer (score 1):

In pointer arithmetic, the "unit" is size of the data type. This is why adding 1 to an `int` pointer pointing to an array element gives the next element in the array, no matter how many bytes size of `int` is in that platform.

Same reason here, when you subtract address of an array element at index 5 from one at index 1, you get **5 - 1 = 4**, no matter what is the data type in the array.

---

On a tangent, slightly related, perhaps helpful for understanding: `sizeof` of an array is still the size in bytes, for the whole array. So if you want to get number of items in an array, you have to do something like

```
int a[] = { ... };
int count = sizeof(a) / sizeof(*a);
```